# Official Dockerfile uses apt-get commands

Tags: elasticsearch, docker, kibana

I want to use Elasticsearch and Kibana in my project.For ease of deployment I would like to use docker containers.From reading some blogs I found that it is recommended to use 2 containers one for elasticsearch and another one for Kibana.

Is this the right approach?

I downloaded the official elasticsearch `Dockerfile` from [elsticsearch repository](https://registry.hub.docker.com/_/elasticsearch/)

However the `Dockerfile` uses `apt-get` commands which work only on `Ubuntu/Debian`

Do they have different `official Docker` files for differnt distributions?

Comment: You might be better off using pre-built docker images instead of building them yourself from `Dockerfile`s (unless you've got custom changes you need to make).

Comment: @neuronaut - where do I find pre-build docker images? Is there a repository for such images?

Comment: Yes, there is such a repository. Try `docker search <some image name>` to search for images you can download. Or check the [docker registry](https://registry.hub.docker.com/). As I recall, you can even upload your own images to share with the community.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need separate Dockerfiles for separate distributions.  The ElasticSearch image is built on top of the official Debian image, and so when you build it from the Dockerfile, apt-get will be run inside a Debian instance, regardless of what the rest of your computer is using.

Answer (score 1):

There are two questions from you.

> I found that it is recommended to use 2 containers one for elasticsearch and another one for Kibana. Is this the right approach?

Yes, keep the container as simple as you can. Treat a container as a process. But I recommend not to build and base on more than 3 related images.

> However the Dockerfile uses apt-get commands which work only on Ubuntu/Debian. Do they have different official Docker files for differnt distributions?

The open source community likes to distribute the image in Ubuntu, but from company level, may prefer RHEL/CentOS or other distributions. So you are fine to write your own `Dockerfile` easily, because the elsticsearch repository's `Dockerfile` is plain text to you for reference.